# C++ #defining enum states

Tags: c++, enums, refactoring

I am wondering if I made a good decision when I defined all states of my enum to their shorter counterparts: just to tidy up the code.
Code:
Enum:

```
enum class ESelectedCharacterState : uint8
{
    SS_WantsWalk,
    SS_WantsJog,
    SS_WantsCrouch,
    SS_WantsProne,
    SS_WantsJump
};
```

Defining:

```
#define WantsWalk ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsWalk
#define WantsJog ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsJog
#define WantsCrouch ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsCrouch
#define WantsProne ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsProne
#define WantsJump ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsJump
```

Case with no #defined enum states:

```
switch (StateSelected)
    {
    case ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsWalk:
        break;
    case ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsJog:
        break;
    case ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsCrouch:
        break;
    case ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsProne:
        break;
    case ESelectedCharacterState::SS_WantsJump:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Case with #defined enum states:

```
switch (StateSelected)
    {
    case WantsWalk:
        break;
    case WantsJog:
        break;
    case WantsCrouch:
        break;
    case WantsProne:
        break;
    case WantsJump:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

This is actually a small bit of code but I use this enum very frequently in my project.

Comment: If you don't want the namespacing `enum class` give you, just use `enum`.

Comment: In this case I need the enum to be an `enum class`

Comment: The preprocessor is The Devil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `typedef` would be a cleaner way to achieve this, by making your `enum`'s type shorter.

```
typedef ESelectedCharacterState ESCS;
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, why not just use `ESCS` as the name of the class in the first place?

Comment: It would not be a very meaningful name. By using a `typedef`, you make the code shorter but can still still find the original, more meaningful type name.